# Getting Errors Whenever I run The React Native Appp

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Failed to construct transformer:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at stableHash (D:\Mustafa\Application\NewApp\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stableHash.js:19:8)
at JsTransformer.getCacheKey (D:\Mustafa\Application\NewApp\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:478:7)
at getTransformCacheKey (D:\Mustafa\Application\NewApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer\getTransformCacheKey.js:39:29)
at new Transformer (D:\Mustafa\Application\NewApp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:147:28)
at D:\Mustafa\Application\NewApp\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:54:29
at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)   
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:509:9) {      
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

I tried So Many Things To Solved This Issue But Not Solved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.